# I want to connect a Google Form with a Google Sheet table that already has data. How can I achieve this?

Tags: google-sheets

I've a table in google sheet with many datas, and now i want that others persons fill this table, but  default google form create other new table in google sheet, and i have indicate that put the data in the old sheet, but dont make that right, why?
[image]

should i copy the datas from Form responses or is there a option in google sheet for conect automatically?

Comment: `should i copy the datas from Form responses` Leaving aside that there is no example of the data on the response form nor an example of a successful outcome... If you "copy" then it becomes permanent entry in "All vocabulary" and can be ammended/ deleted as the need arises; if you use a formula (say, `QUERY`), then the "new" data is displayed on "All vocabulary" but 1) you can't amend or delete it and 2) if the data were deleted from "Form Responses", then the data would disappear from "All vocabulary".